# Error: package reason-react not found or built

Tags: reason, reason-react

After running:

```
bsb -init my-react-login-app -theme react
```

Then, I ran the following to, as I understand, build the project:

```
$npm run build
```

But, I got the following error output:

```
> my-react-login-app@0.1.0 build /Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/my-react-login-app
> bsb -make-world

Package not found: resolving package reason-react in /  
File "bsconfig.json", line 1
Error: package reason-react not found or built , if it is not built
Please run 'bsb -make-world', otherwise please install it
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! my-react-login-app@0.1.0 build: `bsb -make-world`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-react-login-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kevinmeredith/.npm/_logs/2018-06-24T01_36_13_899Z-debug.log
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

See the readme; that template needs you to install reason-react through `npm install` or `yarn add`. After that it should work. We don't check in the entire reason-react dependency chain in the template.